# StackOverflowError - Redundant call onTextChanged

Tags: android, android-edittext, stack-overflow, textwatcher, redundancy

(I'm learning english... therefore, forgive me)

I'm making a app to convert bin, dec and hex. I have three EditText (Number type) and I want to do something when one of the tree contents have changed.

My three EditText:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input1"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="01"
    android:hint="BIN"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input2"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789"
    android:hint="DEC"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input3"
    android:digits="0123456789ABCDEFabcdef"
    android:hint="HEX"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

So I used the following code to handle text changes:

```
EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
EditText input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input3);

input1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String bin = input1.getText().toString();
            String s1 = binToDec(bin) + "";
            String s2 = binToHex(bin);
            input2.setText(s1);
            input3.setText(s2);
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    input2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            try{
                String dec = input2.getText().toString();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(dec);

                input1.setText(decToBin(num));
                input3.setText(decToHex(num));
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe){

            }
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });

    input3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            String hex = input3.getText().toString();
            input1.setText(hexToBin(hex));
            input2.setText(hexToDec(hex) + "");
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
    });
```

But... Everytime the user types in edittext 1, for example, the content of edittext 2 and 3 change. It causes another call to `onTextChanged` and then a infinity stack of call (StackOverflow).
So... Is there a better way to do what I want?
Can someone help me, please?
Thank you!!!

Comment: Why don't you do: `if (!s1.equals(input2.Text)) { input2.setText(s1) }` in your input1 listener? And likewise for the other text fields. Only update the fields if the conversion isn't equal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `TextChangedListener`, I recommend having a button to press once the user is done inputting the text. This eliminates the infinite calls to `onTextChange`. That button can check which one the user entered the numbers into and can change the other `EditTexts` accordingly.

Comment: @MobileDeveloper Please upvote if you think its a good suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

here is what i suggest (the first idea i got):
declare three boolean `editingInput1`, `editingInput2`, `editingInput3` set initially to `false`.

now befor setting the text of an `EditText` (for example `input1`) you set its boolean to true (`editingInput1 = true`), and inside `onTextChanged` of `input1` you test if `editingInput1==true`, if it is the case (it means this call is the result of a .setText(...) and not user input) you reset the boolean to `false` and you return from the method.

here is what your code will look like:

```
EditText input1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input1);
EditText input2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input2);
EditText input3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input3);

boolean editingInput1= false, editingInput2= false, editingInput3= false;

input1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(editingInput1){
            editingInput1= false;
            return;
        }
        String bin = input1.getText().toString();
        String s1 = binToDec(bin) + "";
        String s2 = binToHex(bin);
        editingInput2= true; //it must be set to true befor calling .setText(...)
        input2.setText(s1); 
        editingInput3 = true;
        input3.setText(s2);
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});

input2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(editingInput2){
            editingInput2= false;
            return;
        }
        try{
            String dec = input2.getText().toString();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(dec);

            editingInput1 = true;
            input1.setText(decToBin(num));
            editingInput3 = true;
            input3.setText(decToHex(num));
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException nfe){

        }
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});

input3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        if(editingInput3){
            editingInput3= false;
            return;
        }
        String hex = input3.getText().toString();

        editingInput1 = true;
        input1.setText(hexToBin(hex));
        editingInput2 = true;
        input2.setText(hexToDec(hex) + "");
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
});
```